# Simple HTTP Server + ServerSide Framework Bundle

Tags: http, webserver, web

There are a few tools that I'm developing and one of them requires you to be able to easily create a webserver instance in any folder and run as any user. Something simple like NodeJS, but works with multiple platforms and has an quick and dirty integration with a server-side language.

PHP requires you to setup PHP + Apache. Rails requires Ruby + Ruby Gems and Rails (this is pretty daunting for someone who doesn't normally use a command line). NodeJS is simple, but you need to build everything from scratch.

Basically what the end user to be able todo is:

1. download and extract the tool (which has the webserver itself contained within its setup files) and put everything into a directory.
2. run directory/start (this will work as any user).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution in this case is to use something like `sinatra` or a Java-compiled program which spawns a HTTP web server. Everything else either needs to be compiled or installed onto the system and doesn't support a server-side programming language.

Answer (score 1):

G-WAN can be used to do that because it does not require any configuration (the commands below install the official distribution):

```
 wget http://gwan.com/archives/gwan_linux64-bit.tar.bz2
 tar -xjf gwan_linux64-bit.tar.bz2
 cd gwan_linux64-bit
 sudo ./gwan
```

Of course, you can use your own package with your own HTML pages and C, C++, Obj-C or Java scripts in the compressed archive.

Disclamer: I am involved in the development of this project.

Comment: Not to sure about using this. It's not open source and it doesn't work on OSX and the documentation is too scarce. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose](http://cesanta.com/mongoose.shtml) can do what you want. It also comes with the bundle that include PHP, so everything could be done in single click.